# tabular: Align different symbols in the same column but different rows

Tags: tables, turnstile

I am desperately tying to align formulas appearing in the same column but different rows in a tabular environment:

[image]

The desired result should look exactly like in the above image except that I need the left column to be aligned by "⊢" or "⊨", respectively. I have tried any solution I could get my hands on, but none has really worked yet. If I get the formulas aligned, the Headings are misaligned, and vice versa. I just started with LaTeX. Can anyone help me out?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, headings=optiontohead, headsepline=true, twoside=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{turnstile}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10,colframe=gray!100,fonttitle=\bfseries, title=Übersicht: Syntaktische und semantische Folge]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{r|l}
Metasprachliche Behauptung & Redeweise \\ \hline \rule{0pt}{4ex}
$\{ \alpha_1, …, \alpha_n \} \sststile {}{} \beta$ & $\beta$ ist aus $\{ \alpha_1, …, \alpha_n \}$ herleitbar \\ \rule{0pt}{3ex}
$\sststile {}{} \alpha$ & $\alpha$ ist beweisbar \\[2ex] \hline \hline \rule{0pt}{4ex}
$\{ \alpha_1, …, \alpha_n \} \sdtstile {}{} \beta$ & $\beta$ ist aus $\{ \alpha_1, …, \alpha_n \}$ herleitbar \\ \rule{0pt}{3ex}
$\sdtstile {}{} \alpha$ & $\alpha$ ist beweisbar
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: Thanks for all the helpful answers! Until just a few minutes ago, I did not even know the `phantom` commands. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four columns instead of one would be the answer, but the long heading on the left makes this solution unfeasible.

You can use `eqparbox` facilities. The first mandatory argument to `\eqmathbox` is a unique label to be used for all boxes to equalize.

I also propose a different rendering.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  fontsize=11pt,
  headings=optiontohead,
  headsepline=true,
  twoside=false
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{turnstile}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[3][c]{%
  \eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\m@th#3$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  colback=gray!10,
  colframe=gray!100,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title=Übersicht: Syntaktische und semantische Folge
]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ >{\vphantom{$\Big|$}}r | l }
Metasprachliche Behauptung & Redeweise \\
\hline
$\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\} \sststile{}{} \eqmathbox{A}{\beta}$ &
  $\beta$ ist aus $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \}$ herleitbar \\
${}\sststile{}{} \eqmathbox{A}{\alpha}$ &
  $\alpha$ ist beweisbar \\
\hline \hline 
$\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\} \sdtstile{}{} \eqmathbox{A}{\beta}$ &
  $\beta$ ist aus $\{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \}$ herleitbar \\
${}\sdtstile{}{} \eqmathbox{A}{\alpha}$ &
  $\alpha$ ist beweisbar
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  colback=gray!10,
  colframe=gray!100,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title=Übersicht: Syntaktische und semantische Folge
]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ @{} r @{\qquad} l @{} }
Metasprachliche Behauptung & Redeweise \\
\midrule
$\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\} \sststile{}{} \eqmathbox{B}{\beta}$ &
  $\beta$ ist aus $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \}$ herleitbar \\
\addlinespace
${}\sststile{}{} \eqmathbox{B}{\alpha}$ &
  $\alpha$ ist beweisbar \\
\midrule
$\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\} \sdtstile{}{} \eqmathbox{B}{\beta}$ &
  $\beta$ ist aus $\{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \}$ herleitbar \\
\addlinespace
${}\sdtstile{}{} \eqmathbox{B}{\alpha}$ &
  $\alpha$ ist beweisbar
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The least invasive solution is to replace the `\beta`s in the first column with `\phantom\alpha\llap{$\beta$}`. This makes the `\beta` as wide as the `\alpha`, adding the necessary space on the left so that it remains right-aligned in your first column.

(See also [Align 2 lines horizontally starting from a dash symbol , with the first previous one without subscript and the second previous one with subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620597/align-2-lines-horizontally-starting-from-a-dash-symbol-with-the-first-previous/620810#620810))

Answer (score 0):

You can insert what you want to align in a separate tabular column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, headings=optiontohead, headsepline=true, twoside=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{turnstile}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!10,colframe=gray!100,fonttitle=\bfseries, title=Übersicht: Syntaktische und semantische Folge]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}r@{\hspace{0.5\tabcolsep}}l|l}
            \multicolumn{3}{r|}{Metasprachliche Behauptung} & Redeweise \\ \hline \rule{0pt}{4ex}
            &$\{ \alpha_1, …, \alpha_n \}$ &$\sststile {}{} \beta$ & $\beta$ ist aus $\{ \alpha_1, …, \alpha_n \}$ herleitbar \\ \rule{0pt}{3ex}
            &&$\sststile {}{} \alpha$ & $\alpha$ ist beweisbar \\[2ex] \hline \hline \rule{0pt}{4ex}
            &$\{ \alpha_1, …, \alpha_n \}$ & $\sdtstile {}{} \beta$ & $\beta$ ist aus $\{ \alpha_1, …, \alpha_n \}$ herleitbar \\ \rule{0pt}{3ex}
            &&$\sdtstile {}{} \alpha$ & $\alpha$ ist beweisbar
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]